# SQL Server - Unicode character LRE U+202A in comparison returns wrong result

Tags: sql, sql-server, unicode, collation

In SQL Server 2008, I am trying to compare two strings one with regular text and one with embedded bidirectional text character U+202A (LRE character).  I expected the result to be "Not Equal", but it returns me "Equal".  Am I using the wrong collation sequence?

```
DECLARE @v1 NVARCHAR(40) = N'test'
-- 8234 U+202A LRE (Bidirectional Text)
DECLARE @v2 NVARCHAR(40) = N'T' + nchar(8234) + N'est';

PRINT @v1
PRINT @v2

IF @v1 = @v2 PRINT 'Equal' ELSE PRINT 'Not Equal'
IF @v1 COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS = @v2 COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS 
       PRINT 'Equal' ELSE PRINT 'Not Equal';
IF @v1 COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS_WS = @v2 COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS_WS 
       PRINT 'Equal' ELSE PRINT 'Not Equal';
```

#### Results

```
test
T‪ est
Equal
Equal
Equal
```

Comment: You could use `Latin1_General_BIN` but then you lose the case insensitive matching. Are you sure it isn't actually correct to ignore these control characters when comparing strings? I see similar in `C#` for most comparison options. http://i.stack.imgur.com/Fpcms.png. The documentation for `String.Compare` mentions "ignorable characters"

Comment: Martin, Thanks for you reply.  Latin1_General_BIN works,  but I do want the case insensitive option.  I am trying to save list of folders in a directory and Windows allows me to create two different folders, one with control char and one without.  So I cannot ignore them.